# Remove newline depending on the format of the next line

Tags: sed

I have a special file with this kind of format :

```
title1
_1 texthere
title2
_2 texthere
```

I would like all newlines starting with "_" to be placed as a second column to the line before

I tried to do that using sed with this command :

```
sed 's/_\n/ /g' filename
```

but it is not giving me what I want to do (doing nothing basically)

Can anyone point me to the right way of doing it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following solution:

In [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) the loop is done creating a label (`:a`), and while not match last line (`$!`) append next one (`N`) and return to label `a`:

```
:a
$! {
  N
  b a
}
```

After this we have the whole file into memory, so do a global substitution for each `_` preceded by a newline:

```
s/\n_/ _/g
p
```

All together is:

```
sed -ne ':a ; $! { N ; ba }; s/\n_/ _/g ; p' infile
```

That yields:

```
title1 _1 texthere
title2 _2 texthere
```

Comment: Thank you Birei, Tried your solution but it is not working am afraid

Comment: @Rad: I ran it with your input example with the result you can see here. Tell us (for me and following answers) in what way this solution failed for you.

Comment: I used your solution with the same input as well (original file is huge but with the same format) for some reason I get no change on the file, still showing the original format (\n followed by next line with _), I checked the file and I have no formatting errors, I have the \n at the end of each line, I dont understand why it is not removed with the substitution

Comment: @Rad: Perhaps blank characters at the end of each line or just before the `_`? How about if you check it with some few lines of the file first, as in this example?

Comment: I just checked, I use exactly the same simple example above, your solution makes a lot of sense but I don't know what is wrong though, I double checked no blank characters in the file

Comment: That works though sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n_/ _/g' filename

Answer (score 3):

If your whole file is like your sample (pairs of lines), then the simplest answer is

```
paste - - < file
```

Otherwise

```
awk '
    NR > 1 &&  /^_/ {printf "%s", OFS} 
    NR > 1 && !/^_/ {print ""} 
    {printf "%s", $0} 
    END {print ""}
' file
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;s/\n_/ /;ta;P;D' file
```

This avoids slurping the file into memory.

or:

```
sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e 's/\n_/ /' -e 'ta' -e 'P' -e 'D' file
```

Answer (score 1):

A Perl approach:

```
perl -00pe 's/\n_/ /g' file
```

Here, the `-00` causes perl to read the file in paragraph mode where a "line" is defined by two consecutive newlines. In your example, it will read the entire file into memory and therefore, a simple global substitution of `\n_` with a space will work.

That is not very efficient for very large files though. If your data is too large to fit in memory, use this:

```
perl -ne 'chomp; 
          s/^_// ? print "$l " : print "$l\n" if $. > 1; 
          $l=$_; 
          END{print "$l\n"}' file
```

Here, the file is read line by line (`-n`) and the trailing newline removed from all lines (`chomp`). At the end of each iteration, the current line is saved as `$l` (`$l=$_`). At each line, if the substitution is successful and a `_` was removed from the beginning of the line (`s/^_//`), then the previous line is printed with a space in place of a newline  `print "$l "`. If the substitution failed, the previous line is printed with a newline. The `END{}` block just prints the final line of the file.